# SQL query for the number of cases when a value of column1 (non-unique) can't be found within any record where column2 meets a basic criteria

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

I am doing a beginners' SQL tutorial and I started to wonder whether a simple SQL query on this table: http://www.sqlcourse2.com/items_ordered.html could tell the number of items  (also 1) which have only been purchased more items at a time, so there is no record which contains the quantity column with a value of 1 AND the item. I am really beginner at this so please try to keep it simple.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you please explain a bit more question is not clear.please give expected result as well

Comment: So let's say there was no purchase of item a and b where the customer bought only one of these items. Result: 2 - there are two items of which haven't ever been a puchase where the customer bought one (a and b).

Comment: and how you are going to tell weather item i purchased or not where is that information which column ?

Comment: These are the columns: customerid, order_date, item, quantity, price.

Comment: Every item have been purchased at least once, but some have only been more at a time (quantity > 1)

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the fascinating world of SQL.

Well - I'm not giving you the answer, but a hint (after all, it's a training and your own thinking and finding the solution would be the best way for you to learn something new).

The way you formulate your question is somewhat puzzling.

When I combine what you ask with what is possible with SQL, the question that would make sense to me would be that you need to list (or count, I did not understand that very well) the `item`s (or the complete rows in the table with matching `item`, that was not clear either),  that were *never* sold with a `quantity` of 1.

If that's what you need, you will need a subselect to get all distinct `item`s that were sold with a `quantity` of 1, and select the rows from your base table whose `item` value is not in the list you get from the subselect.

Do you need more hints?

Marco

Comment: Well, thank you very much for this detailed answer! After thinking a bit about the problem it seems it's just me not being enough mature with SQL.. But I am grateful you mentioned subselects, I will work it out from here.